# Multiple IF statement not returning correct result in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an IF Statement that I'm using to assign a person points based on values in specific columns. For some reason, it's returning 076 for every row. I've tried it several ways, including without the OR, and it returns the same thing. Any ideas?

```
=IF(OR(C2=1&E2=1&F2=1),100,0&IF(OR(C2=1&E2=1&F2<>1),76,0&IF(OR(C2<=1&E2=1&F2<>1),48,0&IF(OR(C2<=1&E2=1&F2=1),72,0&IF(OR(C2<=1&E2<>1&F2=1),24,0)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably should use `AND` not `OR` and the `&` should be commas inside the `OR`

```
=IF(AND(C2=1,E2=1,F2=1),100,
0&IF(AND(C2=1,E2=1,F2<>1),76,
0&IF(AND(C2<=1,E2=1,F2<>1),48,
0&IF(AND(C2<=1,E2=1,F2=1),72,
0&IF(AND(C2<=1,E2<>1,F2=1),24,0)))))
```